# How to control the redirect behavior in Azure B2C Custom Policy for consecutive password errors?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am currently working on Azure B2C Custom Policy development, specifically focusing on the login process.
However, I am facing an issue related to controlling the redirect behavior in the case of consecutive password errors.
In our frontend implementation, we have a comment suggesting that the frontend is unable to control the redirect behavior for this particular scenario.

Currently, when a user enters consecutive incorrect passwords, the Azure B2C portal redirects to a "fail page" on redirect URL with "/error", while the application redirects to a "blank page."
This behavior is not desired, and we would like to have more control over the redirect behavior in such cases.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to configure the redirect behavior in Azure B2C Custom Policy for consecutive password errors.
Specifically, I would like to understand how to modify the redirect destinations for the Azure B2C portal and the application when consecutive password errors occur.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!